# Tiktok Webscraping using Beautifulsoup, But not getting video urls or video ids from channel

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm **scraping** tiktok channel (channel link: https://www.tiktok.com/@agt?)  using beautifulsoup. So basically I need to take the video links from this channel. For example:  the first video link is https://www.tiktok.com/@agt/video/6787079306066660614, but I couldn't find it when I scrape the channel.

Below is the code that I'm using currently:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/@agt'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

**Please let me know if the problem is not clear enough.**

Comment: have you found soup content?

Comment: Yes. But this text is not there is the html '@agt/video/6787079306066660614'. When I do inspect element in google chrome it shows the text

Comment: yes, actually it takes time in loading page after page load all content is present in HTML. comment line of headless and you can see that page is loading.you have to wait for page fully loaded

Comment: Ohh ok, I got it. Can you please suggest me how to set wait time to  load the full page?

Comment: refer https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Even after setting up wait time also that video part is not loading.

Answer (score 1):

TikTok has some specific certifications and handshaking method. This makes it very hard to scrape the website.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34275227)

Comment: I think it does answer the question. I have the same issue as the OP and this resolves my confusion.